# Finding the Optimum

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following data through observation.

- X:3600;3000;2400;1800;1200;600
- Y:0.05;0.06;0.06;0.08;0.11;0.17
- Z:64005; 57401; 51235; 42760; 32303; 24823

X is the variable that i can change and then i get the correlated results of Y and Z.

[image: Image of the graph]

So i want to find the optimum of X to get the lowest value of Y and the lowest value of Z. 
How can i do that?

Comment: You have no a priori model for the dependences?  Just glancing at the data it looks as if $Y$ is a decreasing function of $X$, so if you want a small value for $Y$, take a high value for $X$.  Similarly, $Z$ appears to be an increasing function of $X$ so to minimize $Z$ take a low  value for $X$.  Not sure what else you are hoping for...I mean, you could guess that $Y$, say, is "leveling off" and won't drop much further.  But, honestly, absent some external knowledge that's not much better than a wild guess.

Comment: Ok. So i did the Polynomial Fit in excel, getting the following formula:
y = 9E-11x2 - 1E-05x + 0.3824
So i solved that for X and get for X: -18634 and 129746.
Doesn't work for me. Then i am just getting the function. I was kkind thinking about linear programming to set 2 more restriction for my solution area. But can i really think about an solution area or do i make a logical mistake here?

Comment: Don't know what you mean by "solution area".  That quadratic looks just fine to me.  Not a bad fit at all.  It puts the minimum $Y$ value a bit above $,05$ (the data point which realizes the $.05$ appears a bit below the fitted curve).  If you accept the function, then you can draw your rectangle easily.  Of course, you need not accept the function...but then I think you need a good reason to reject it.  If you increase the degree of the polynomial you'll get a better fit but at what cost?  You are almost certainly just fitting to noise at that point.

Comment: Just for fun, I fit a cubic through the points. Naturally, the fit looks even better.  The inflection point appears to come around the data point $(57,401,.06)$ . But then of course the $Y$ values begin to decline sharply.  Does that fit your intuition for the data better?

Comment: I agree, the function looks fine and fits well.
So now i have my polynomial function describing my result. So i still need the minimum value of Y and Z. But they are contrary, so i need to find the best trade-off in my function. So the constraint is that Z can't be smaller than 20000. Can i do a funtion like Min= Y+Z and Y= 9E-11*z^2 - 1E-05*z + 0.3824. So in the end i want to minimize F= z+ 9E-11z2 - 1E-05z + 0.3824. I tried it but the final function dosn't look good, the minimum is negative :(